# Moving EE to AWS

Tags: ee2, migration, aws

Our website is hosted by a private company in UK... They designed the website and are also hosting it. I am thinking of moving the website to Amazon Web Services.

Has anyone ever tried this and what services on AWS was used?

How secured is AWS with respect to EE websites?

Comment: I think this is a little too broad honestly. Can you be more specific? What concerns do you have specifically after looking into AWS website hosting and how it might work with EE?

Comment: I am concerned about the services that would be used on AWS to host EE Websites.